# First 32GB of a 4TB ext4 filesystem overwritten. How to recover?

Tags: linux, partition, ext4, data-recovery

Due to an accident specifying a block device, the first 32GB of a 4TB ext4 filesystem on a SATA disk was overwritten by the dd command with the contents of a USB flash drive.

fdisk -l /dev/sda reports the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeaad24fe

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048  8388607  8386560    4G  6 FAT16
/dev/sda2       8388608 73924607 65536000 31.3G 83 Linux
```

parted shows the following:

```
GNU Parted 3.5
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA ST4000NM0165 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4295MB  4294MB  primary  ext4
 2      4295MB  37.8GB  33.6GB  primary
```

Side Note: I'm not sure why parted thinks the file system is ext4 while fdisk shows it as FAT16, but it could possibly be related to the fsck that I tried to run before understanding what had happened. I attempted to run "e2fsck /dev/sda1", and answered yes to the following question:

```
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>? yes
```

It then came back with the statement that the partition size didn't match the physical size, and it was at that point I stopped without proceeding further. (I apologize I don't have the full text of my aborted attempt with fsck. I retyped the above from memory, and I only answered yes once.)

This is what used to be on the disk:

This disk was originally auto-partitioned+formatted by the installer of Ubuntu 18.04. It was an ext4 filesystem, with a single partition, sda1, that took the entire drive. There is a separate, NVME drive that is the system partition, and this disk was configured as a secondary data disk. The parameters will be whatever the Ubuntu 18.04 installer would have selected as the defaults in this instance.

I understand any data in the first 32GB of this disk is irretrievably lost. But the data on this disk is critically important. Is there any way to recover what was on the remaining 99% of the drive?

Can someone recommend steps that would allow me to recreate the original filesystem?

Edit: gdisk -l /dev/sda shows the following:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Warning: Invalid CRC on main header data; loaded backup partition table.
Warning! Main and backup partition tables differ! Use the 'c' and 'e' options
on the recovery & transformation menu to examine the two tables.

Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: ERROR
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: ERROR
Backup partition table: OK

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT
```

Comment: You ran `dd` on the partition, or the entire device? From the `fdisk` output, I assume the device. If so, you destroyed the partition table aswell as the (first) superblock, inode table...

Comment: I hope you have a backup. Otherwise, you would need to use `parted` and try to recreate the original partition layout, then use recovery software and pray (superblock etc. are usually repeated across the partition).

Comment: Yes. I ran it on the block device for the disk and overwrote the partition table. Unfortunately, I do not have a backup. I need to recover as much as I can.

Comment: Create a complete image of this disk, to atleast have a backup of its broken state. Do not perform any write operations on the disk. Interact with (a copy of) the cloned image.

Comment: If 4TB drive, it should have been gpt partitioned (not old MBR/msdos) which has a backup partition table at end of drive. What does this show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` Best to work with cloned image if making changes.

Comment: Hi oldfred, the output is too long to paste in comments. I edited the main question. The short answer is that it looks like the backup partition table is still intact.

Comment: AbelianMemes, "_the output is too long to paste in comments_" - please don't put any updates in the comments. They are to seek clarification from you about your question. Your responses would generally be in the form of additional information, which you should add to your question. Ideally you would add information as if you had supplied it in the first instance, so that your question remains a coherent whole rather than "question / edit / update / another update / another edit". The idea is to make the question as easy to follow as possible so that as many people as possible might answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a full "dd" copy of the partition to another device, just for safekeeping in case something goes wrong.

In general, `e2fsck` should be able to recover from such an issue, subject to loss of the overwritten metadata.  The superblock, root directory, journal, and other metadata would be lost.  However, the superblock and other critical metadata have multiple backups later in the partition, so the majority of the data should be intact.

You *might* need to specify a backup superblock location, like `e2fsck -fy -B 4096 -b 11239424 /dev/sda2`.  The backups are stored in groups numbered 3^n, 5^n, 7^n, with 128MiB group size, so if you clobbered up to 32 GiB that is 256 groups and the next highest group number is `7x7x7 = 343`, so the backup superblock is in block `343x32768 = 11239424`.

It will put everything into the `lost+found` directory, so you will have to identify files/directories by their content, age, etc.